# Upgrading from VS 2013 to VS 2017 PostSharp + Kendo MVC exception

Tags: c#, kendo-asp.net-mvc, postsharp

I am upgrading a project from VS 2013 to VS 2017 and when I build project in VS 2017, I get this exception

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Unhandled exception (3.1.44.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release):     PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Cannot find a method named '.ctor' with signature '(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext, Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.IJavaScriptInitializer, Kendo.Mvc.IUrlGenerator) : void' in scope 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Chart`1'  (module = 'Kendo.Mvc.dll').
>      at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.MethodDefDeclarationCollection.GetMethod(String name, IMethodSignature signature, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
>      at 
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodRefDeclaration.GetMethodDefinition(BindingOptions
>   bindingOptions)    at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.IndexGenericInstancesTask.Execute() 
>   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
>   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()    at
>   PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()    at
>   PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation
>   projectInvocation)

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Additional Info**:- Issue occurs at this line of code

```
var chartBuilder = new Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ChartBuilder<ProjectsQueryHandler>(chart)
                                .Name("TChart")
            .Title(title => //title
                title
                .Text(GetChartTitle(fieldName))
                .Color(colorCode)
                )
                                .Legend(legend => legend
                                    .Visible(true).Position(Kendo.Mvc.UI.ChartLegendPosition.Top)
                                );
```

Comment: It seems that your issue has to do with PostSharp and not with Kendo MVC. Take a look at the various citations here on SO and on Google related to PostSharp--you might have a PostSharp versioning or .NET Framework referencing issue on your hands that should be rather easy to fix.

Comment: PostSharp 3.1.x is quite old, it is likely that we've fixed this bug in a newer version. It may be also generics/etc. Also, C# compiler started to use CLI features it did not use before in the meantime.